# When i include the "The largest no. is:$' as MSG in data segment, i don't get the result

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHPra.png)

```
msg db 'The largest no is:$'

lea dx, msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

if i don't include those lines, i get 9 as the largest which is correct. but i if include that prompt display, i get "a" as output. why?
(if i don't write something, it doesn't let me upload so. ....................................................................................................................................................)

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
array db 1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8
msg db 'The largest no is:$'
largest db ?
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

lea si, array
mov cx, 10
mov al, [si]
findlargest:cmp al, [si+1]
jnc skip
mov al, [si+1]
skip:inc si
loop findlargest

mov largest, al

mov ah, 0     ;;; clear the screen
mov al, 2
int 10h

mov dl, 13                      ;;; new line
mov ah, 2
int 21h
mov dl, 10
mov ah, 2
int 21h

lea dx, msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov dl, largest
add dl, 48             ;; convert number to character to print
mov ah, 2
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch     ;; exit
int 21h
main endp
end
```

Comment: you have an array of 10 elements, so you only need to compare 9 times. `mov cx, 9` will fix it

Comment: @Tommylee2k you are the man.... love you . it really works, that was the mistake, dang. Assembly is so so so picky. haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overflowing the byte `array`.

First you load `al` via `mov al, [si]` to hold a starting value.

Then you loop ten iterations referencing`[si+1]`, which means you compare `al` against `array+1` through `array+11`.  And `array+11` holds the character 'T', and is captured as the highest, so then when you add 48 to 'T' you get a funny character.

If you omit the `msg` then `array+11` most likely holds zero, so that won't be taken as the highest.

Comment: Eidit , ```mov cx, 9``` made it works! , i was comparing out of the array so.